# Apply functions to multiple columns with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I have 2 functions like this one:

```
def wind_index(result):
    if result > 10:
        return 1
    elif (result > 0) & (result <= 5):
        return 1.5
    elif (result > 5) & (result <= 10):
        return 2


def get_thermal_index(temp, hum):

    return wind_index(temp - 0.4*(temp-10)*((1-hum)/100))
```

When I'm trying to apply this function like this:

```
 df['tci'] = get_thermal_index(df['tempC'], df['humidity'])
```

I got this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What else can I do to get a new column for my DataFrame using those functions??

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output? [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def get_thermal_index(temp, hum):
    return (temp - 0.4*(temp-10)*((1-hum)/100)).apply(wind_index)
```